# Header not using all passed in values

Tags: php, redirect

I need to redirect some urls.

Formerly I had

```
http://mysite.com/foobar/?section_id=1234
```

These are no pointing to

```
http://mysite.com/foobar/1234
```

I put the following in my code to handle attempts to visit the old url:

```
$section_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'section_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

if ( $section_id ) {
    header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
    header( "Location: ".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]."/foobar/".$section_id );
}
```

The problem is that after redirecting the url is:

```
http://mysite.com/foobar
```

The needed id is not there!

In that `if` statement if I do

```
echo "Location: ".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]."/foobar/".$section_id;
```

I get:

```
http://mysite.com/foobar/1234
```

but then the redirect still fails to include the `1234` part.

Why is this and how to I get it to redirect as desired?

---

Output of lynx -head -dump http://mysite.com/foobar/1234 (i.e. it looks correct to me)

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2012 18:55:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=c35123456; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Pingback: http://mysite.com/xmlrpc.php
Link: <http://wp.me/mysite>; rel=shortlink
Location: mysite.com/foobar/1234
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Redirects are a lot easier using `mod_rewrite` if you can

Comment: Did you confirm that `http://mysite.com/foobar/1234` does not redirect you to `http://mysite.com/foobar/`? `$ lynx -head -dump http://mysite.com/foobar/1234` could help you determine that, likewise to determine if your header is correct as well.

Comment: @Vague I did try it and it looks correct to me (I appended the output to my question)

Comment: I do see an error, the `Location` header must have an absolute and valid URL as its value. I.e. must begin with `http://`. I dont think this is the cause of your problem though

Comment: Actually that is the problem! Thanks Vague. Make this a proper answer so I can mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Location` header must have an absolute and valid URL as its value. I.e. must begin with `http://`.

**Edit**: The `Location` header value can also be an absolute path starting with a forward slash `/`.

Comment: As anyone reading this will see my `Location` header (in the lynx output example) does NOT start with `http://`. This fixed it.